# How to check if list elements are in dict of lists with multiple values per key?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two data structures, a list "unique" and a dict of lists "check":

```
print(unique):
[['apple'], ['red'], ['5']]
```

```
check = {
   "numbers": {
      "allowed_values": {
         "fruit": ["apple"],
         "colour": ["red"],
         "number": ["5", "8"],
                }
            }
        }
```

What I want to do is to iterate over both and check if `unique` only contains elements that are also specified in `check` values. My previous attempt were:

```
for val_unique, val_check in zip(unique, list(check.values())):
   if ~(val_unique in val_check):
      print("There are elements in unique which are not defined in check!")
   print("All good!)
```

and

```
if ~all((val in list(check.values()) for val in unique)):
   print("There are elements in unique which are not defined in check!")
print("All good!)
```

But so far, both don't work as they are either always printing true or false no matter the actual content of the lists. I think the issue comes with `number` and its two values per key there. How can I fix it, so that checks are performed whether each element of unique is also in check? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to use `~`, probably consider `numpy where`. If however working with dataframe, then `np.where`, or `map()` or `mask` or even `panda where` applied on the datagrams. Depending on your use case or data size, they might be better than iterations

Comment: "What I want to do is to iterate over both and check if unique only contains elements that are also specified in check values" **What does "check values"** mean? For this given example `check`, **what values** should be checked against, and **what is the logic** that tells you this?

Comment: There are multiple things wrong with each attempt, and they honestly don't make much sense for the task, regardless of your answer to my clarifying question. So rather than "how can I fix it", it would be much better to scrap those attempts, **clarify the requirement**, and simply ask about how to do it. However, this is a multi-step problem, so you should try to break it down into logical steps before asking about it on Stack Overflow. For example: can you write code that takes `check` as input, and gives a simple list of the **actual** values to check against?

Comment: I am sorry if my initial question was not stated precisely enough. The requirement is that for each element of the `unique` list (['apple'], ['red'], ['5']), a boolean test is done whether this element is also present in the `check` dict values (['apple'], ['red'], ['5', '8']). My problem is that the last key value pair of `check` contains two values in the list (['5', '8']), so I am wondering if these two values within one list falsify the comparison between the unique and the check values.

Comment: To be even more precise, the data structures have the following contents:

`print(unique) = [['apple'], ['red'], ['5']]`
`print(list(check.values())) = [['apple'], ['red'], ['5', '8']]`

I just want to iterate over every element of the `unique` list and check whether it is also existing in the `check` list elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
#collect directory values from dictionary
check_list = list(check['numbers']['allowed_values'].values())
match_index = 0 #initialize index

for i,j in zip(unique,check_list): #iterate through both lists

    #inspect whether the 'check' contains the   corresponding 'unique' value
    if j.__contains__(i[0]) == True: match_index+=1

print('check contains '+str((match_index*100)/len(check_list))+'% of unique')
```

Hope this helps!